# How do I tell the size of my braking discs?

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake

Looking to replace my hydraulic disc brakes but intend to use the old discs. How do I tell the size of the discs to ensure I purchase the right brakes?

Comment: You need to match the mounting (6 bolt IS or Centerlock). As for telling the size, you can use a ruler to measure the diameter. Alternatively, I'm guessing these are the original brakes on the bike and you can look at the rotors spec'd OEM on the manufacturer's website. Or just walk into your LBS and ask them for a new rotor.

Comment: @Batman It seems the asker wants to keep their rotors and replace the callipers, whereas you seem to be advising about how to replace the rotors while keeping the callipers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The disc that you are talking about is in fact called the rotor.

Rotor size is measured by diameter, ie. edge to edge through the centre. The size may also be etched on to the rotor which would be more accurate than measuring yourself. There are a number of common IS (International Standard) sizes of rotor from 140mm through to 203mm.

Callipers only come in one size but use various adapters/spacers to fit the rotor. Once you know what rotor you have you purchase a new brake set which may or may not include the adapter you need. Your current brake callipers would use the right size adapter for the rotor you are using, but may not be right for the brake you wish to purchase, companies have proprietary systems for attaching the calliper such as Avid's CPS which require special adapters or spacers.

Additionally there are two types of mounts for callipers post and IS. Most callipers are made to use post mounts while most frames still have IS mounts on the real dropout. An IS mount is like a fin with two holes in it while a post mount is two posts. IS adapters are used to allow the calliper to be fastened to the bike. Most recent forks are post mount.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually marked at the rotor. Check that first.

Comment: Voting to leave - its a short answer but there's not a lot more to say.

Answer (score 0):

As DWGKNZ says you could measure these. Alternatively, you could search online for your bike make/model & look at the specification. This would save you the time of taking the wheel off and measuring (and note front/back might be different sizes). This assumes that it has not been changed since you bought the bike.